# Why is Python's io.BytesIO gets really slow when size increases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle, bytesio

I'm using Python 3.5.5 from Anaconda distribution. 
To build a web service I'm using bottle 0.12.13, specifically POST request.

In a POST request, the request's data is at `request.body` which is a an `io.BytesIO` object. To get it's value i use the `getvalue()` according to https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.

The server accepts a json string of few files decoded to bytes. When I send only one file the `getvalue()` is really fast but 2+ files make it increadiblly slower. Example:

```
start_time = time.time()
postdata = request.body.getvalue()  # byte stream
print('getvalue time: {}'.format(time.time() - start_time))
print('len(postdata): {}'.format(len(postdata)))
```

Output for 1 file:

```
getvalue time: 0.0005793571472167969
len(postdata): 12522
```

Output for 2 files:

```
getvalue time: 0.14102387428283691
len(postdata): 21684
```

Even though the size of 2 files is much smaller then the default bottle's `BaseRequest.MEMFILE_MAX` of 102400 bytes, I resized it to 1024000 and still no improvement.

Does anyone know the reason for it/a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like `getvalue` is more than just a simple getter; it may have to do some parsing in order to combine multiple values into one string.

Comment: Can you think of how to overcome this major performance drop?